# toilet basin rattling valve

Tags: toilet, valve, noise

our toilet water basin valve makes a terrible rattling noise when filling up with water. It's the left side tube making that. Any idea about possible solutions beyond calling a plumber and replacing the valve?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the toilet fill valve is an easy DIY project.  You can buy a new one for less then $20.00.

I found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB0VHdhUR1s) that is a good tutorial.

*I am not affiliated with them*.

You only need minimal tools and to know how to turn off water supply valve.

There is a valve just under your toilet on the side with the flush lever. Turn the valve handle clockwise until it stops. Flush the toilet to drain the water out, there should not be any water coming out of the tube if the valve is shut completely. 
I like to take a big sponge and soak up the remaining water in the tank but you can use a bucket to catch the extra water that comes out when you remove the fill valve.

Use a pair of adjustable pliers to loosen the nut of the top of the supply hose that connects to the fill valve on the bottom of the tank (*basin*). Once the supply line is disconnected  there is a plastic nut that holds the fill valve in place on the bottom of the tank, use the pliers to loosen this and then remove by hand, remove the rubber gasket as well. Now you can pull the valve out of the tank. ( *if there is any extra water in the tank it will run out of the hole so have your bucket under the hole*. )

Now you just reverse the process with the new valve and follow the instructions to adjust the fill level, ( the shut off point that tells the valve when to stop filling )

Yes even you can do it. ;).